# Div overflowing page width

Tags: html, css

I'll be straightforward with my issue. I copied the template for my site from another site where it worked perfectly. So far I've fixed most issues except for one I cannot find out what the problem is. Whenever the webapp is loaded on my iPhone, the width of the page is set to the device default yet I am able to scroll the page horizontally and see blank space [image: View of what I see] Has anyone had this issue before, and if so, is there a fix for it? The page can be viewed here: **Link removed** Feel free to view the source code. (I didn't write most of it, it's very messy but has worked very well so far). Thanks for the help!

**Edit:** I assume it's a div making the page overflow like it is, that's why I threw it in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using Adobe Shadow to debug the issue: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/

And yes, I understand that this is a suggestion and not an answer.

Comment: Your suggestion solved my problem. Adobe Shadow is very impressive. Thanks for the help!

Comment: anytime - it's been a life saver to me as well :)